# Polars groupby + value_counts

Tags: python, group-by, python-polars

I need some help with **polars**:

I have a dataframe with a categorical values column

```
┌───────────────────┬──────────────┬────────┐
│ session_id        ┆ elapsed_time ┆ fqid   │
│ ---               ┆ ---          ┆ ---    │
│ i64               ┆ i32          ┆ cat    │
╞═══════════════════╪══════════════╪════════╡
│ 20090312431273200 ┆ 0            ┆ intro  │
│ 20090312431273200 ┆ 1323         ┆ gramps │
│ 20090312431273200 ┆ 831          ┆ gramps │
│ 20090312431273200 ┆ 1147         ┆ gramps │
│ …                 ┆ …            ┆ …      │
│ 20090312431273200 ┆ 5197         ┆ teddy  │
│ 20090312431273200 ┆ 6180         ┆ teddy  │
│ 20090312431273200 ┆ 7014         ┆ teddy  │
│ 20090312431273200 ┆ 7946         ┆ teddy  │
└───────────────────┴──────────────┴────────┘
```

And I want to transform the fqid-column to look like this:

```
┌───────────────────┬─────────────┬────────────┬────────────┐
│ session_id        ┆ fqid_gramps ┆ fqid_intro ┆ fqid_teddy │
│ ---               ┆ ---         ┆ ---        ┆ ---        │
│ i64               ┆ i32         ┆ i32        ┆ i32        │
╞═══════════════════╪═════════════╪════════════╪════════════╡
│ 20090312431273200 ┆ 1           ┆ 1          ┆ 4          │
└───────────────────┴─────────────┴────────────┴────────────┘
```

That is, I would like to:

- Groupby over `session_id`,
- Make a value_counts() over `fqid`,
- Rename columns so that it would be 'fqid_' + `category`,
- Turn them into columns (transpose),
- Add them to the result.

Technically, I could achieve this without groupby by using something like

```
column_values = train['fqid'].value_counts().with_columns(pl.concat_str(pl.lit('fqid' + '_').alias('fqid'), pl.col('fqid').cast(pl.Utf8))).transpose()
column_values = column_values.rename(column_values.head(1).to_dicts().pop()).slice(1)
```

But when I am trying to make an aggregating function from this replacing `train['fqid']` with `pl.col('fqid')` and making a `groupby('session_id').aggregate(func('fqid'))` it gives me nothing but errors like `AttributeError: 'Expr' object has no attribute 'with_columns'`.

Could you kindly suggest a proper way of making this operation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Starting from

```
train=pl.from_repr(
     """┌───────────────────┬──────────────┬────────┐
        │ session_id        ┆ elapsed_time ┆ fqid   │
        │ ---               ┆ ---          ┆ ---    │
        │ i64               ┆ i32          ┆ cat    │
        ╞═══════════════════╪══════════════╪════════╡
        │ 20090312431273200 ┆ 0            ┆ intro  │
        │ 20090312431273200 ┆ 1323         ┆ gramps │
        │ 20090312431273200 ┆ 831          ┆ gramps │
        │ 20090312431273200 ┆ 1147         ┆ gramps │
        │ 20090312431273200 ┆ 5197         ┆ teddy  │
        │ 20090312431273200 ┆ 6180         ┆ teddy  │
        │ 20090312431273200 ┆ 7014         ┆ teddy  │
        │ 20090312431273200 ┆ 7946         ┆ teddy  │
        └───────────────────┴──────────────┴────────┘""")
```

we can do

```
(
    train
        .group_by(
            (piv_idx:='session_id'),
            (len_id:='fqid'),
            maintain_order=True) 
        .len()
        .pivot(values='len',
               index=piv_idx,
               columns=len_id,
               aggregate_function='first')
        .select(
            piv_idx,
            pl.exclude(piv_idx).name.prefix(f"{len_id}_")
            )
)

shape: (1, 4)
┌───────────────────┬────────────┬─────────────┬────────────┐
│ session_id        ┆ fqid_intro ┆ fqid_gramps ┆ fqid_teddy │
│ ---               ┆ ---        ┆ ---         ┆ ---        │
│ i64               ┆ u32        ┆ u32         ┆ u32        │
╞═══════════════════╪════════════╪═════════════╪════════════╡
│ 20090312431273200 ┆ 1          ┆ 3           ┆ 4          │
└───────────────────┴────────────┴─────────────┴────────────┘
```

Since you want the count (now len) of the fqids, you need to include that in the `group_by`. Next, we do a [`pivot`](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/dataframe/api/polars.DataFrame.pivot.html#polars.DataFrame.pivot) to make the results wide. The output of pivot doesn't keep the original column name so we have to add that back manually. We do that in a `select` by first taking the `session_id` and then adding to that every column except `session_id` with the prefix 'fqid_' to get the final desired result.

Incidentally, I'm not using `value_counts` because it returns a list of structs so we can't do, for example, `train.select(pl.col('fqid').value_counts().over('session_id'))`

I used the [walrus operator](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.8.html) to assign the column names to variables in the `group_by` so that you only need to change the columns in one place without repeating yourself. in the pivot and select.